# Testing triggers for fulltext search in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing, full-text-search, django-queryset

I'm adding a search engine to a Django project, and thus set up SearchVectorFields on several models, with custom triggers.

I would like to unit-test that my columns of type `TSVECTOR` are updated  when the instance of a Model changes.

However, I've been unable to find any information on how to test the content of a SearchVectorField ... I can't compare `my_document.search` to `SearchVector(Value("document content"))` or similar, because the first one seems to be string-like, while the latter is an object.

**TL;DR**

More precisely, with the model:

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    ...
    content = TextField()
    search = SearchVectorField()
```

and trigger:

```
-- create trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
    NEW.search := to_tsvector(COALESCE(NEW.content, ''))
    return NEW;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-- add trigger on insert
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS search_trigger ON myapp_document;
CREATE TRIGGER search_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON myapp_document
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE search_trigger();
-- add trigger on update
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS search_trigger_update ON myapp_document;
CREATE TRIGGER search_trigger_update
BEFORE UPDATE OF content
ON myapp_document
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.content IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.content)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE search_trigger();
```

How can I test that when I create a new `Document` instance, its `search` field is populated **with the right values** ? Same question for updating an existing `Document` instance, but the answer should be fairly similar.

Thanks for any hint ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can compare string representation of your SearchVectorField values:

```
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Document


class DocumentTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        Document.objects.create(content='Pizza Recipes')

    def test_document_search(self):
        document_list = list(Document.objects.values_list('search', flat=True))
        search_list = ["'pizza':1 'recip':2"]
        self.assertSequenceEqual(document_list, search_list)
```

Comment: But then you have to manually construct your `search_list`...
I wanted to avoid that, because 1) I'm mocking everything -> I would need to either stop mocking objects for these tests or implement a function that builds the `search_list` given an input 2) I would need to know the exact result I expect

More precisely, I know eg that `search` reflects the content of `content`, but with the above described method, I would need to use PostgreSQL to know the expected value of `search`, because it would be inefficient and redundant to implement the creation of the search vector in Python.

Comment: Usually I have only processed value in test to compare with the one I expect from a comparison and it just works, try it and report if it work for you too. Your last specified needs was not in your question, if you want a specific answer I suggest to you to add the content of your last comment in the main question.

Comment: If you're like me an mock everything in your tests, compare `Document.objects.values_list('search', flat=True)` with `[item.search_vector for item in Document.objects.annotate(search_vector=SearchVector('content', config='yourconfig'))]`